# Check logic for altitude of a triangle using d3

Tags: math, d3.js, geometry, 2d, computational-geometry

I have [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lulaco/1/edit?js,output) that shows my working.

In the jsbin, I am trying to draw a line through the altitude through point A (1, 1) that is perpendicular to Line BC which has points B (6, 18) and C (14, 6).

The way I have worked this out is to try and get 2 equations into the form `y = mx + c` and then rearrange them to `y -mx = c` and then solve them through simultaneous equations using matrices.

I have this altitude function that does the work:

```
function altitude(vertex, a, b) {
  var slope = gradient(a, b),
      x1 = - slope,
      y1 = 1,
      c1 = getYIntercept(a, slope),
      perpendicularSlope = perpendicularGradient(a, b),
      x2 = - perpendicularSlope,
      y2 = 1,
      c2 = getYIntercept(vertex, perpendicularSlope);
  
  var matrix = [
    [x1, y1],
    [x2, y2]
  ];
  
  var result = solve(matrix, [c1, c2]);
  
  var g = svg.append('g');

  g.append('line')
    .style('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .attr('x1', xScale(vertex.x))
    .attr('y1', yScale(vertex.y))
    .attr('x2', xScale(result.x))
    .attr('y2', yScale(result.y));
}
```

I first of all get the gradient of BC using this function

```
var gradient = function(a, b) {  
  return (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);
};
```

Which is -1.5 and from that I can get the perpendicular gradient using this function:

```
var perpendicularGradient = function (a, b) {
  return -1 / gradient(a, b);
};
```

I make that to be 0.66666 or (2/3).

I get the 2 equations to look like this:

```
y + 1.5 = 27
y -0.6666666666666666 = 0.33333333333333337
```

I have some functions in the jsbin that will solve these simultaneously using matrices and cramer's rule, the main one being solve:

```
function solve(matrix, r) {
   var determinant = det(matrix);
   var x = det([
      [r[0], matrix[0][1]],
      [r[1], matrix[1][1]]
    ]) / determinant;
  
   var y = det([
     [matrix[0][0], r[0]],
     [matrix[1][0], r[1]]
   ]) / determinant;
  
  return {x: Math.approx(x), y: Math.approx(y)};
}

function det(matrix) {
  return (matrix[0][0]*matrix[1][1])-(matrix[0][1]*matrix[1][0]);
}
```

I get the coordinates of the intercept to be roughly (12.31, 8.54).

The problem is, it does not look right on the diagram.

Have I taken a wrong step somewhere?  I think my calculations are right but I would not rule out them being wrong.  It might be down to scale perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to find projection of point A onto line BC.

Let's make vectors
**Q** = **C** - **B**
**P** = **A** - **B**
normalized (unit length):
**uQ**  = **Q**/ |**Q**|

Needed projection point **D** is
**D** = **B** + **uQ** * DotProduct(**P**, **uQ**)

For your example A(1,1),  B(6,18), C(14,6)

**Q** = (8, -12)
|**Q**| = Sqrt(8*8+12*12)~14.4
**uQ**= (0.55, -0.83)
**P**=(-5,-17)
DotProduct(**P**, **uQ**)=0.55*(-5) -(0.83*-17)=11.39
**D** = (6+0.55*11.39, 18-0.83*11.39) = (12.26, 8,54)

So your calculation gives right result (though approach is not very efficient), but picture is not exact - **different scales of X and Y axes deform angles**.

**P.S:** Second line `width = 660 - margin.left - margin.right,` makes the picture more reliable

Comment: I have not encountered vectors.  how are the scales different

Comment: I see at your picture - 20 units are about 10 cm at OY axis, and about 17 cm at OX. Try to draw at grid paper

Comment: Ha, you were right, I had different scales.  Thank you!

What is the mathematical technique using vectors?  Do you have a link?